# What is the probability distribution for the integrated effect of sparse $\pm1$ random events?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-walk, binomial-distribution, poisson-process

I am working with a process that can be modeled as sparsely occurring jumps of either +1 or -1.

I am interested in finding the probability distribution of the net (integrated) effect of this random process over an arbitrary time interval $T$.  I assume that I have an overall occurrence rate $\lambda$ as well as the probabilities $p(+1)$ and $p(-1)=1-p(+1)$ of a given event being $\pm 1$.

---

I assume by CLT that this process should be related to the binomial distribution over time, but I'm not sure how to calculate the variance.  If I make the assumption that occurrence rates can be separated into $\lambda_+$ and $\lambda_-$ for the two event outcomes, then I believe I can calculate the mean as:

$\mu(T) = (\lambda_+ - \lambda_-) T$

However, I don't understand how to get the variance of this distribution.  (Does this somehow relate back to Poisson process?).  Any insight would be much appreciated!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "sparsely occurring"? Are you essentially considering a Poisson process, except that jumps may also go down by $1$?

Comment: Yes! I think so.  I have a distribution of time between events.  It could maybe be approximated as exponential.  It actually looks like a Poisson distribution but with a really long tail.

Comment: The distribution of time between events is discrete or continuous?

Comment: Technically continuous, but my data is discrete so I think we can assume it is discrete.

Comment: Are the times between jumps i.i.d. at least? Otherwise it will be very difficult to model this as a stochastic process.

Comment: Yeah, I was worried about this part.  I actually think they can be effectively modeled as occurring in discrete time and i.i.d. if the occurrences in the data are quantized.  In reality, there is less of a chance of occurrence in a short time interval after an event has occurred.